# Java can't save Output Stream to a file

Tags: java, stream, output

This code works fine on Computer A and doesn't work on Computer B ... I can't understand Why..
Nothing Exceptions or anything else ....On Computer A log file  was created , on computer B log file was't  created.
Computer A and B have the same Java version... 
Do you have any ideas?

```
    String str = "cmd /C  dir tools>1.log";
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

PS
this code works fine on both computers

```
    String str = "cmd /C  dir tools";
```

Comment: You should use Java's built-in file APIs.

Comment: did you check permissions

Comment: try to out the command specified by string but remain **/K**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the process' output stream to save the output to a file correctly.

You can do this by creating a Process object and saving that to a file:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(str);
InputStreamReader reader = p.getInputStream();
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);
String line = null;
while ((line = buffer.readLine() != null) {
  //write stuff to file here
}
```

Comment: I know about  this method and  it works  fine  but  I don't  understand   why  my method  doesn't work

Comment: I believe this has been discussed in SO before, but I cant find the article.  Instead look here: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4 Section 4.6 should explain it

Answer (score 0):

Going on what SLaks said -- it is your best bet to use the built-in file APIs. 
Here is a [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/) for a general tutorial

Using these APIs will take out any strange environment issues from Computer A to B...to C and so on.

Comment: OK I know about that but I don't understand why my method doesn't work... Could  you  explain  what's  wrong  in my case